# One-vs-Rest algorithm and out-of-the-box multiclass algorithm gives different results

Tags: scikit-learn, classification

Can someone explain why the `OneVsRestClassifier` gives different result than the out-of-the-box algorithm?

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier, OneVsOneClassifier

X = [[1,2],[1,3],[4,2],[2,3],[1,4]]
y = [1,2,3,2,1]

X_pred = [[2,4], [5,4], [3,7]]

dummy_clf = OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier(verbose=0, class_weight="auto", loss='modified_huber', random_state=0)) # first case
#dummy_clf = SGDClassifier(verbose=0, class_weight="auto", loss='modified_huber', random_state=0) # second case

dummy_clf.fit(X, y)
dummy_clf.predict_proba(X_pred)
```

First case:

```
array([[ 0.5,  0.5,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.5,  0.5,  0. ]])
```

Second case:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

OneVsRest gives you the probability of X_pred for all of the classes, thus the first and last test cases have a value for multiple classes (that sum to 1). The classifier is trained on all classes.

OneVsOne trains a classifier on all class pairs. For all class pairs, the class predicted most is the winner, so you only get one prediction per instance.